# Obtaining estimated covariance matrices for HMM from depmixS4 package

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am using the [depmixS4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/index.html) package for hidden markov models.

I am applying it on a joint multivariate gaussian distribution for n vectors with m states. My question concerns obtaining the estimated parameters - in particular:

**My question**
How can I obtain the estimated m covariance matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In extension of the above example, the following script shows how to extend to the 3-dimensional case. Beware that the input / output parameters use the variance/covariance matrix and not standard deviations, as suggested by the names in the above example

```
# DepMixS4- Multivariate Normal
# Exmaple from the Help Page extended to three dimensions        

library(depmixS4)        

# generate data from two different 3-dim normal distributions
#mean 
m1 <- c(0,0,1) 
# the first one has equal covariance of size 0.3
# Sigma1 denotes the covariance matrix
Sigma1 <- matrix(c(2,0.3,0.3,0.3,1,0.3,0.3,0.3,1),nrow=3)
#mean
m2 <- c(1,0,0)
# the second one has equal covariance of size -0.3
Sigma2 <- matrix(c(2,-0.3,-0.3,-0.3,1,-0.3,-0.3,-0.3,1),nrow=3)        

y1 <- mvrnorm(1000,m1,Sigma1)
y2 <- mvrnorm(1000,m2,Sigma2)
# Check that Sigma1_11 is indeed variance:
# The following gives approx 2, as it should be
var(y1[,1])    


# this creates data with a single change point
y <- rbind(y1,y2)        

# now use makeDepmix to create a depmix model for this 3-dim normal timeseries
# response is a 2-dim list of response models. 
rModels <-  list()
rModels[[1]] <- list(MVNresponse(y~1))
rModels[[2]] <- list(MVNresponse(y~1))        

trstart=c(0.9,0.1,0.1,0.9)        

transition <- list()
transition[[1]] <- transInit(~1,nstates=2,data=data.frame(1),pstart=c(trstart[1:2]))
transition[[2]] <- transInit(~1,nstates=2,data=data.frame(1),pstart=c(trstart[3:4]))        

instart=runif(2)
inMod <- transInit(~1,ns=2,ps=instart,data=data.frame(1))        

mod <- makeDepmix(response=rModels,transition=transition,prior=inMod)        

fm3 <- fit(mod,emc=em.control(random=FALSE))      

summary(fm3)
```

The last command gives output (only the last part)

```
Response parameters 
    Re1.coefficients1 Re1.coefficients2 Re1.coefficients3 Re1.Sigma1 Re1.Sigma2 Re1.Sigma3 Re1.Sigma4 Re1.Sigma5 Re1.Sigma6
St1        0.92688362        0.04410173      -0.004027074   2.042186 -0.3347858 -0.2467676   1.066815 -0.3113216  0.9507479
St2        0.03676585        0.05259029       1.022748735   2.037637  0.4235656  0.3856682   1.146025  0.3401500  0.9763637
```

The estimated variance/covariancematrix with fields

```
 s_11 s_12 s_13
      s_22 s_23 
           s_33
```

(Empty fields can be filled in by symmetry)
 are given in the output as
 Re1.Sigma1, ... , Re1.Sigma6

Answer (score 1):

I asked the authour of the package directly and got the following answer:

> See `?makeDepmix`
>
> if you run the example with multivariate data like so:
>
> ```
> # generate data from two different multivariate normal distributions
> m1 <- c(0,1)
> sd1 <- matrix(c(1,0.7,.7,1),2,2)
> m2 <- c(1,0)
> sd2 <- matrix(c(2,.1,.1,1),2,2)
> set.seed(2)
> y1 <- mvrnorm(50,m1,sd1)
> y2 <- mvrnorm(50,m2,sd2)
> # this creates data with a single change point
> y <- rbind(y1,y2)
>
> # now use makeDepmix to create a depmix model for this bivariate normal timeseries
> rModels <-  list()
> rModels[[1]] <- list(MVNresponse(y~1))
> rModels[[2]] <- list(MVNresponse(y~1))
>
> trstart=c(0.9,0.1,0.1,0.9)
>
> transition <- list()
> transition[[1]] <- transInit(~1,nstates=2,data=data.frame(1),pstart=c(trstart[1:2]))
> transition[[2]] <- transInit(~1,nstates=2,data=data.frame(1),pstart=c(trstart[3:4]))
>
> instart=runif(2)
> inMod <- transInit(~1,ns=2,ps=instart,data=data.frame(1))
>
> mod <- makeDepmix(response=rModels,transition=transition,prior=inMod)
>
> fm2 <- fit(mod,emc=em.control(random=FALSE))
> The output gives this: 
>
> > summary(fm2)
> Initial state probabilties model 
>             St1     St2
> (Intercept)   0 -10.036
>
> Transition matrix 
>        toS1 toS2
> fromS1 0.98 0.02
> fromS2 0.00 1.00
>
> Response parameters 
>     Re1.coefficients1 Re1.coefficients2 Re1.Sigma1 Re1.Sigma2 Re1.Sigma3
> St1             0.125             1.024      1.346      0.873      1.272
> St2             0.716             0.100      2.068      0.285      0.888
> ```
>
> Sigma1-3 are the (unique) values of the covariance matrix.